# Hibernate - Mapping three tables with a single save

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a project that will use Hibernate to store the objects to the database.

If I simply insert (save) an object that does not contain a mapping with another table everything works fine. However, I have a case where there is a connection between three tables. The tables are the Asset, MonetaryValue and CurrencyType (see below).

When an Asset is inserted, the monetaryValueType must be provided (by the user ) along with the currency type. Asset holds a OneToOne relation with the MonetaryValueType and MonetaryValueType holds a OneToOne relation to the  CurrencyType Table. 
More specifically, below you will find the database tables.

```
Asset(asset_id,ownerIID,valueID,samID), where valueID is the foreign key to the MonetaryValueType Table (OneToOne undirectional mapping)

MonetaryValueType(mvID, mValue,currencyId), where currencyID is the foreign key to the CurrencyType Table (OneToOne undirectional mapping)

CurrencyType(currencyID,currField,currValue,currSymbol).
```

The problem is that every time I create the asset object and I am calling the asset service to save the element, Hibernate either create a select query that tries to select from a database table I did never define or Inserts in the currency field with wrong column names (i.e. currency_field instead of currField etc.)

I've tried to play with all the Cascade types but nothing seems to work.

```
Asset.java

@Entity
@Table(name="asset")
public class Asset implements java.io.Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="assetID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long assetID;

    @Column(name="ownerID")
    private long ownerID;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="valueID")
    private MonetaryValueType monetaryValueType;

    @Column(name="samID")
    private long samID;
------------Constructor, Getters , Setters-----
```

```
MonetaryValueType.java

@Entity
@Table(name="monetaryvaluetype")
public class  MonetaryValueType{

    @Id
    @Column(name="mvID",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="mValue")
    private double mValue;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="currencyId")
    private CurrencyType currency;
------------Constructor, Getters , Setters-----
```

```
CurrencyType.java

@Entity
@Table(name="currencytype")
public class CurrencyType implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="currencyID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int currencyID;

    @Column(name="currField")
    private  String currField;

    @Column(name="currValue")
    private String currValue;

    @Column(name="currSymbol")
    private String currSymbol;
------------Constructor, Getters , Setters-----
```

Every entity holds its own DAO,DAOImpl, Service and ServiceImpl class. For instance, for the asset class the DAOImpl and ServiceImpl can be found below:

```
AssetDAOImpl.java

@Repository
public class AssetDAOImpl implements AssetDAO{
    private Logger logger   = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    //entity manager field
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;




    @Override
    public List<Asset> findAll() {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        //create a query
        Query theQuery =
                currentSession.createQuery("from asset",Asset.class);
        //execute query and get result list
        List<Asset> aModelElements = theQuery.getResultList();
        //return the results
        return aModelElements;
    }

    @Override
    public Asset findById(int theId) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Asset insert(Asset assetElement) {

        //Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        boolean success = false;
        try {

            entityManager.persist(assetElement);
            logger.info("Asset -> {}", assetElement);
            return assetElement;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
AssetServiceImpl.java

@Service
public class AssetServiceImpl implements AssetService {

    private Logger logger   = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private AssetDAO assetDAO;

    @Autowired
    public AssetServiceImpl(AssetDAO theAssetDAO){
        assetDAO=theAssetDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Asset> findAll() {

        return assetDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Asset findById(int theId) {
        return assetDAO.findById(theId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Asset insert(Asset theAsset) {
        assetDAO.insert(theAsset);
        return theAsset;

    }
...
```

The class that I use to fill the asset class (and all its children) is:

```
 UniqueIDGenerator uniqueIDGenerator = new UniqueIDGenerator();
            CurrencyType currencyType = new CurrencyType();
            Asset asset = new Asset();
            MonetaryValueType monetaryValueType = new MonetaryValueType();

            currencyType.setCurrValue(ctx.value().monetaryValueType().currency().CurrencyType().getText());
            currencyType.setCurrSymbol("currency");

            monetaryValueType.setId(uniqueIDGenerator.nextId());
            monetaryValueType.setmValue(Double.parseDouble(ctx.value().monetaryValueType().mValue().getText()));
            monetaryValueType.setCurrency(currencyType);

            asset.setMonetaryValueType(monetaryValueType);
            asset.setAssetID(uniqueIDGenerator.nextId());
            asset.setOwner(uniqueIDGenerator.nextId());
            asset.setSamID(uniqueIDGenerator.nextId());
            assetService.insert(asset);
```

Whenever I call the class mentioned above, I get the following error:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        element1
        (datefrom, dateto, description, name, statusid, samid) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-08-05 20:19:00 INFO  MyClass:63 - the result is:true
Hibernate: 
    select
        monetaryva_.mvid,
        monetaryva_.currency_id as currency3_57_,
        monetaryva_.m_value as m_value2_57_ 
    from
        monetaryvaluetype monetaryva_ 
    where
        monetaryva_.mvid=?
2019-08-05 20:19:01.084  WARN 56712 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2019-08-05 20:19:01.084 ERROR 56712 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'monetaryva_.currency_id' in 'field list'
```

As you can see, hibernate created columns (currency_id instead of currencyID) that are not in accordance with my database tables even though I used the @Column annotation.

Comment: If the relationships among these entities are all one to one to one then what exactly is the point of three separate entities and and three separate tables?  Not that it's necessarily wrong to split them up like that, but it adds complication and reduces efficiency without providing any offsetting benefit that is evident to me.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: @JohnBollinger Because there are other relationships that use these tables as well/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following two lines in your application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: Wow! That's actually solved the problem! Thank you very much!